# Using Sysic to Define Augmented Plant for H-infinity Control (Robust Control Toolbox)

Tags: matlab, optimization, robust

I have been doing some tutorials on robust control. Previously I have been using "sysic" to define the augmented plant to control with "hinfsyn", however, I came across "augw" recently and when comparing the results for the mixed-sensitivity scheme, I saw there do not give the same results.

[augmented plant for mixed sensitivity hinfsyn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHMDi.png)

The issue is that I must be defining the interconnection scheme incorrectly in "sysic".

I include a simple example to demonsrate:

```
G=ss(-1,2,3,4);   % plant to be controlled 
w0=10;     % desired closed-loop bandwidth
A=1/1000;  % desired disturbance attenuation inside bandwidth
M=2 ;      % desired bound on hinfnorm(S) & hinfnorm(T)
s=tf('s'); % Laplace transform variable 's'
W1=(s/M+w0)/(s+w0*A); % Sensitivity weight
W2=0.1;                % Empty control weight
W3=(s+w0/M)/(A*s+w0); % Complementary sensitivity weight

% check gamma for mixed sensitivity hinf
[K,CL,GAM,INFO]=mixsyn(G,W1,W2,W3);

% augmented plant method 1
systemnames = 'G W1 W2 W3';
inputvar = '[ r(1);u(1)]';
outputvar = '[W1;W2;W3;G]';
input_to_G = '[u]';
input_to_W1 = '[r-G]';
input_to_W2 = '[u]';
input_to_W3 = '[G-u]';
sysoutname = 'G';
cleanupsysic = 'yes';
sysic;
nmeas = 1; nu = 1; gmn=0.5; gmx=20000; tol = 0.1;

% augmented plant method 2
P = augw(G,W1,W2,W3);

% method 1
[K,Pcl,gam1 opt] = hinfsyn(G,1,1,'GMIN',gmn,'GMAX',gmx,'method','lmi');
% method 2
[K,Pcl,gam2 opt] = hinfsyn(P,1,1,'GMIN',gmn,'GMAX',gmx,'method','lmi');
```

I get gamma values:

```
gam1 =

   1.0000e+03


gam2 =

    1.1183
```

I am not sure what I am missing here, as I believed they are equivalent. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to the augmented plant using sysic is :

```
% augmented plant method 1
systemnames = 'G W1 W2 W3';
inputvar = '[r;u]';
outputvar = '[W1;W2;W3;r-G]';
input_to_G = '[u]';
input_to_W1 = '[r-G]';
input_to_W2 = '[u]';
input_to_W3 = '[G]';
sysoutname = 'G0';
cleanupsysic = 'yes';
sysic;
```